# Best practice to use mocked data in an express node app for local development

Tags: node.js, express, mocking

I have an application that uses react for frontend and nodejs/express for backend. My backend endpoints call yet another http service. In my development environment, I want to use mock data instead of calling the external http service. A short example:

```
app.get('/api/data', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    // Make an external API call 
    const response = await axios.get('https://someapi.com/do/1');
    const data = response.data;

    res.json(data);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Failed to fetch data from the external API' });
  }
});
```

Instead of getting data from the api, I want to get it from a dummy json. Here are following ways to do this:

1. Set an environment variable and add if/else condition. Something like following:
   I do not prefer this as it appears to introduce lot of if/else and code will get bloated doing this for so many endpoints.
2. Create another express app copying original app and return mock data instead of calling endpoints.
3. Any other solution?

Code using if/else

```
app.get('/api/data', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    if(process.env.USE_MOCK ==true) {
      res.json(return_mock_data_here)
    }
    else {
       // Make an external API call 
      const response = await axios.get('https://someapi.com/do/1');
      const data = response.data;

      res.json(data);
    }
  } catch (error) {
      res.status(500).json({ error: 'Failed to fetch data from the external API' });
  }
});
```

Code using mocked express server

```
app.get('/api/data', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    res.json(return_mock_data_here)
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Failed to fetch data from the external API' });
  }
});
```

I am not aware what will be a better practice to do it this way. Any pointers will be greatly helpful.